# playing music from stream

Tags: python, pi-2, node.js, streaming, pi-1

I have a raspberry pi 2 model B and a raspberry pi 1 (I think, it doesn't have any version number on it and I have had it for a long time and I don't quite remember exactly the version).
I think the raspberry pi 2 would be better to do it on but It's already in use and I would want to use the other pi.

So I want to play music on the speakers connected to the pi from a stream, which I already have the URL for.
How would I do this without any external modules and libraries. Please note that this is a learning project so I would like to do it without external libraries.
I know both javascipt(nodejs) and python, so both of the two languages could be used in solutions.

Sorry for my English, if anything is unclear please comment and I'll try to clarify it.

Comment: Please read https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask before posting This question show now research or effort to solve the issue before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand "playing music from a stream". Is it a stream like Twitch stream or is it a URL of a .mp3/.wav file? If it is the first type, could you please provide me the URL? Thanks!

I'm not sure about the first type streaming. But for the second one, you can use wget to download the file and play it with [omxplayer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/audio/). Or you can use [pygame](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Book%3A_Making_Games_with_Python_and_Pygame_(Sweigart)/03%3A_Pygame_Basics/3.22%3A_Playing_Sounds) with Python to play music.

Comment: It's like an mp3 that has no end and keeps going, almost like a stream on Twitch but for audio only. Also is there a way in pygame to pass in a URL instead of the path for the audio file?

Comment: You have to read the URL somehow (wget, urllib3, ...) to play it. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674416/python-realtime-audio-streaming-with-pyaudio-or-something-else

Comment: nevermind I used omxplayer to play the stream URL, turns out I'm just simply dumb :)

Comment: @lolfail If this answers your question, please tick the big checkmark on the left.